# php/sql JOIN two tables of data from $variable created from dropdown selection

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie, so new that I hope I can make this question clear enough.
Database has two tables;

```
tblnames > [clmid, clmnames]
tblpol > [clmDate, clmCategory, clmnames, clmComment]
```

My goal is: The user selects a category from a dropdown list, clicks a button and returns all rows of `[tblpol.clmDate, tblnames.clmnames, tblpol.clmComment]` data that match the user selection value `$Category`.

`tblpol.clmnames` contains only a names id so I don't want to display that, I want to display the full text name which is stored in tblnames.clmnames  I think I need a JOIN to do this. Here is my attempt which doesn't work of course and I get the error `Unknown column 'XYZ' in 'where clause'`

```
 $clmCategory = $_GET['clmCategory'];
 $clmCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($clmCategory);
 $query = "SELECT tblpol.clmDate, tblnames.clmnames, tblpol.clmComment
           FROM tblpol
           INNER JOIN tblnames ON (tblpol.clmnames = tblnames.clmnames)
           WHERE clmCategory = $clmCategory";
```

Comment: XYZ is a string, you're not quoting your variable to treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fred. How do I quote the variable ? Like this > WHERE clmCategory = '$clmCategory'";

Comment: yep, you're welcome. someone posted an "answer" for you below. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php also on your query which would have signaled the syntax error

Comment: so.... question still open?

Comment: Thanks Fred so much. That was the solution.

Comment: you're welcome. I'll head back to my Espresso machine then ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did ask the question well.

But just need to put quotation marks around the category variable, like so:

```
WHERE clmCategory = '$clmCategory'";
```

Also, you might need to join on the id rather than the name, like this:

```
INNER JOIN tblnames ON tblpol.id = tblnames.id
```

But I don't see your table structure so you might have to update the column names I used.

Comment: wow.. I've been banging my head for two days over this.. those quotes was the solution. Thank you so much & Fred too.